# How do I resize Twitter URL display with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I am currently setting up some code to display a social media link. I was given this code from the Twitter, but I need to resize it to 340x400. I tried adding style="width:340; height:400;" to the end of the `<a>` tag as well as adding a `<div style="width:340; height:400;">` around the code and neither worked. I also considered switching this to an iFrame, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
<p><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/seuniversity?ref_src=twsrc%5egoogle%7ctwcamp%5eserp%7ctwgr%5eauthor">Tweets by @SEUniversity</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, can you provide some more info? It looks like what you provided is a text link. Should this be an image?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that is 340x400.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="340" data-height="400" href="https://twitter.com/seuniversity?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by seuniversity</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Additionally, you can go [here](https://publish.twitter.com/) to customize your output.